# How can I use unit testing framework on sharepoint 2007?

Tags: unit-testing, sharepoint-2007

I have a MOSS2007 application and now I want to unit test on the application.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: How about unit testing framework that is integrated with Visual Studio 2008 or later?
Can I use it to unit test MOSS application?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Typemock Isolator for SharePoint](http://site.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-for-sharepoi)

Answer (score 1):

Typemock Isolator for SharePoint is the standard tool. The problem you've got is that so much of the SharePoint OM cannot be stubbed or mocked. Typemock will help you do this. Microsoft Research is also developing [Pex and Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/default.aspx), though you'll need an MSDN license to use Moles.

Comment: Moles is freely available on Visual Studio Gallery.

Comment: My mistake. It's Peli's product!

Comment: No harm taken. We do have a confusing licensing story.

Answer (score 1):

[Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/moles) from Microsoft Research allows to test MOSS code in isolation. There are 2 tutorials ([here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/pexsharepoint.pdf) and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/pexsharepointbehaviors.pdf)) that explains how to use Moles for SharePoint unit testing. Moles is freely available on Visual Studio Gallery.